# Likert scale 5point, before and after effect, 380 samples

Tags: t-test

My hypothesis about meditation leading to  success in life. Success is measured in four variables. Number of questions 44  and sample size 380.Responses are gathered on 5 point likert scale with before and after effect. What would be the appropriate statistical approach

Comment: Thanks for response. It is same group. Responses are taken after a week gap

Answer (score 0):

Did you have two groups of participants; one who received meditation and one who didn't?

You might consider running separate repeated measures ANOVAs for each of your four outcome measures with pre- and post-scores as your within subjects factor and meditation vs control as your between subjects factor. Or you could use ANCOVA with the pre-score included as a covariate, the post-score as the dependent variable. Alternatively, if you want to examine relationships between your four outcome measures you might consider MANOVA.